# Registration Page,validation and send data to php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm new to Web programming it might be a silly doubt but still asking.

Edited my previous question.I have Register.html page and Welcome.php. In Register.html i have a form in which if username is not entered then call alert('Enter name'). Otherwise go to Welcome.php page print his username which he entered.

My problem is if i don't enter the username and still submit the form then the alert message doesn't pop up.

```
**This is my Register.html code** 
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validation(){

if(document.getElementById('username').value=="")
{
    alert('Enter name');
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Enter the details</h1>
<form method="post" action="Welcome.php">
<table >
<tr>
    <td>Username:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username"></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Confirm Password:</td>
<td><input type="password" name="Repass" id="Repass" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="register" onclick="validation();"></td>

</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>

</html>



**This is my Welcome.php**
<?php
echo "Welcome".$_POST['username'];
?>
```

Comment: Post your code here instead.

Comment: `Hoping to get answers asap`? Well we are `Hoping to see some actual code asap`.

Comment: @jackkds7 Edit your question with that code, don't post it in the comments.

Comment: You's be better doing some testing and study time...

Comment: Wait I will post the code.

Comment: Your `<input type="text" id="username">` does not have a `name` attribute, ie. `name="username"`, so that is why `$_POST['username']` is empty. javascript uses the `id="username"`, but php needs a `name="username"` -> `<input type="text" id="username" name="username">`.

Comment: I added name attribute also but still it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your answer seems to be lacking a lot of required information that is needed to answer your question. However from what you have currently in your question and from personal experience I would probably just use PHP for the result your looking for.

So let's say your form resembles something like this...

```
<form action="" method="post" id="register">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Your username" />
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email address" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Your password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Join" />
</form>
```

I did try and do something similar to this in one of my previous projects, but in the end I did something like this...

```
<?php if($register_success = 1) { ?>
<h1>Welcome <?php echo $_POST['username']; ?></h1>
<p>This is a static registration message with instructions on what to do further...</p>
<?php } else { ?>
<form action="" method="post" id="register">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Your username" />
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email address" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Your password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Join" />
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

and to receive output like this validate with PHP and set a the value of `$register_success` like so...

```
//In no errors statement where you would register the user set the value of $register_success to 1

} else {
    //Register the user
    $register_success = 1;
}
```

I hope that this answer helped your question.

Comment: @jackkds7 Vote your answers that you have found most useful as it helps the rest of the community find the most helpful and liable answers